# How can I get list of all element css attributes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to get list of elements all css attributes. How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want to get all the css properties of an element?

Comment: Yes, I need to get all css attributes that my selected element has.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-ele

Comment: Useful answer: `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.body, '')`
got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614963/how-do-i-get-all-supported-css-properties-in-webkit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Copying the source from [SO1004475 - jQuery CSS plugin that returns computed style of element to pseudo clone that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-ele) - Please follow link and upvote there if you find it useful.

It seems ridiculous, but this is probably your best option - makes `.css()` with no arguments get an object with all this stuff set.

```
jQuery.fn.css = (function(css2) { 
    return function() {
        if (arguments.length) { return css2.apply(this, arguments); }
        var attr = ['font-family','font-size','font-weight','font-style','color',
            'text-transform','text-decoration','letter-spacing','word-spacing',
            'line-height','text-align','vertical-align','direction','background-color',
            'background-image','background-repeat','background-position',
            'background-attachment','opacity','width','height','top','right','bottom',
            'left','margin-top','margin-right','margin-bottom','margin-left',
            'padding-top','padding-right','padding-bottom','padding-left',
            'border-top-width','border-right-width','border-bottom-width',
            'border-left-width','border-top-color','border-right-color',
            'border-bottom-color','border-left-color','border-top-style',
            'border-right-style','border-bottom-style','border-left-style','position',
            'display','visibility','z-index','overflow-x','overflow-y','white-space',
            'clip','float','clear','cursor','list-style-image','list-style-position',
            'list-style-type','marker-offset'];
        var len = attr.length, obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            obj[attr[i]] = css2.call(this, attr[i]);
        }
        return obj;
    };
})(jQuery.fn.css);
```

Note that this doesn't capture all possible CSS properties, particularly new ones for CSS3. Here is a [list of all standard CSS and stable CSS3 properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference), and here's one of [hyphen-prefixed vendor-specific properties](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) (such as `-moz-border-start`). If you really want all of them, you can glean them from there.

Comment: Agreed - but I think its what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Edited to avoid polluting the `jQuery.fn` namespace with a `css2` function. Otherwise, this is great stuff.

Comment: @gnarf Note that jQuery since 1.9 can take an array of properies in its css method so the loop is not needed there.

Comment: nice script, i see no box-shadow?

Answer (score 16):

As of jQuery 1.8, you can do:

```
$( "#yourElement" ).css( "cssText" );
```

Which uses the underlying `window.getComputedStyle( element ).cssText`. That's the simplest way.

Comment: @EJTH I'm the author of that code inside jQuery ;-)

Comment: Thanks! You helped me solve the problem of moving stuff to a certain container in the dom without any styling getting lost! :-) I use it for some pet project, make a HTML page fall apart with box2d...

Comment: WOW! I love this! Simply the best way if you want a dump of every CSS property in existence!

Answer (score 3):

For inline styles:

```
var styles = $("#someelement").attr("style");
```

From there, you should be able to split this string if you need to loop the styles.

To check individual styles, check the docs:

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS

Comment: I need also attributes that are set in css

Comment: Perhaps explain what you're trying to accomplish in your question. You may be better off checking for individual styles, or using classes and using .hasClass() - gnarf has a link below otherwise

Answer (score -4):

```
$("#div1).css("background-color");
```

will return the background color property of an element with id div1.

[css( name )](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css)

Sorry, I don't know a way to get all the CSS attributes using jQuery.