# How do I get all supported CSS properties in WebKit?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, webkit

In Firefox, Opera and IE I can get them via:

```
>> for (k in document.body.style) console.log(k)
-> opacity
   background
   height
   textAlign
   .
   ... long list ...
   .
   pointerEvents
```

In WebKit the result is quite different:

```
>> for (k in document.body.style) console.log(k)
-> cssText
   length
   parentRule
   getPropertyValue
   getPropertyCSSValue
   removeProperty
   getPropertyPriority
   setProperty
   item
   getPropertyShorthand
   isPropertyImplicit
```

---

**Update:** latest [WebKit does enumerate over CSS properties in HTMLElement.style](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23946) same way all the over browsers do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

```
>> document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.body, '')
-> CSSStyleDeclaration
   0: "background-attachment"
   1: "background-clip"
   2: "background-color"
   3: "background-image"
   4: "background-origin"
   5: "background-position"
   6: "background-repeat"
   7: "background-size"
   8: "border-bottom-color"
   9: "border-bottom-left-radius"
   ...
```

Thanks to Anton Byrna for his [solution](http://twitter.com/itrelease/status/11958025479).

---

One problem still remains: `getComputedStyle()` does not return shortcuts like `background` and `border`.

Comment: Iterating `document.body.style` provides the Javascript style properties.  `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.body, '')` only has the CSS properties.  e.g. `backgroundAttachment` vs. `background-attachment`.

Comment: any way to get all their possible hints of values like 'inherit',percentage, text-bottom; for each of them. even if using js.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the Javascript access, but you may look up all supported properties (even the proprietaries) here: [CSS property names](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSPropertyNames.in).

Comment: Link for CSS property names changed to http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSPropertyNames.in