# Is there a way to get all valid keywords for CSS property?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Round two. First was "[How do I get all supported CSS properties in WebKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614963/how-do-i-get-all-supported-css-properties-in-webkit)".

I'm looking for magic `CSSkeywords` function:

```
CSSkeywords('float') --> ['left', 'right', 'none']
CSSkeywords('width') --> ['auto']
CSSkeywords('background') --> [
  ["repeat", "repeat-x", "repeat-y", "no-repeat"], 
  ["scroll", "fixed"], 
  ["top", "center", "bottom", "left"],
  /*regexp for color*/,
  /*regexp for url*/,
  "none"
]
```

Comment: I really doubt this is possible -- even if browser's stored this kind of info they probably wouldn't reveal it in the DOM API, and even if, by some miracle, they did, there would be a whole lot of proprietary rubbish to avoid.

Comment: Firebug seems to know what they are :-)

Comment: Have a look at Firebug's source. `content/firebug/lib.js` lists all of the properties and their associated keyword values.

Comment: Firebug hardcode them. It's just one list for Mozilla. I also need it for Opera, WebKit, and IE. So, I have to keep up to date at least 4 lists. And I don't even mention different versions of browsers.

Comment: I see much hardcoding in your future.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to write that yourself.

Comment: “It always seems impossible until it’s done.” – Nelson Mandela

Answer (score 1):

A [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17771932/157247) was posted, which I [answered with the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17771950/157247). Posting it here in case that other question gets deleted.

---

No, I don't think there's anywhere in the standard browser environment (such as it is!) accessible with JavaScript that lists all of the possible values of CSS properties. (Not even for those properties that do have a constrained set of possible values.)

This information is covered by various specifications, though, [the CSS 2010 snapshot](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/) covers the main body of it (the [list of properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/#properties) is particularly useful for what you're describing). The [CSS Basic User Interface Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/) CR also has a lot of stuff (`box-sizing`, for instance), and there are several further proposals covered [in various additional CRs and LCs [and even WDs] on the W3C website](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work).

Those are primary sources. (I prefer to cite primary sources.) There seems to be a pretty good secondary source [here](http://cssvalues.com/), without *(as of this writing)* massive adverts, and *with* links per property to both primary (W3C) and useful secondary (MDN) sites.

Answer (score 0):

There are some code that you could take a look for instance open source browser codebase and some of them are using real great autocomplete algorithms that you could base your work on.

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/third_party/blink/renderer/core/css

Here is an example of the `Animation Priority properties` from `chromnium`:

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/third_party/blink/renderer/core/css/css_properties.json5#L548-L553