# Get all available values of css property

Tags: javascript, css

Can I get all values of a css property with JavaScript? For example can I get all values (poniter, resize, etc ) of "cursor" property?

I know I can get a value of a property from element

```
element.style.cursor
```

But this obviously can't show me all possible values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think there's anywhere in the standard browser environment (such as it is!) accessible with JavaScript that lists all of the possible values of CSS properties. (Not even for those properties that do have a constrained set of possible values.)

This information is covered by various specifications, though, [the CSS 2010 snapshot](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/) covers the main body of it (the [list of properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/#properties) is particularly useful for what you're describing). The [CSS Basic User Interface Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/) CR also has a lot of stuff (`box-sizing`, for instance), and there are several further proposals covered [in various additional CRs and LCs [and even WDs] on the W3C website](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work).

Those are primary sources. (I prefer to cite primary sources.) There seems to be a pretty good secondary source [here](http://cssvalues.com/), without *(as of this writing)* massive adverts, and *with* links per property to both primary (W3C) and useful secondary (MDN) sites.

Comment: Recently got [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/vXf9t/) working in webkit, but doesn't seem to work in Firefox. It's still neat ?

Comment: @adeneo This seems to be the "user agent stylesheet" defined by the browser. I saw this on a page with no stylesheets, every elemnt has some style.

Comment: @adeneo That will list the available properties, (or at least the ones applicable to an element) not the value domain of a given property.

Comment: Didn't say it would, it lists all styles, there's no way to get every possible value defined in the standard for each style.

Comment: @adeneo: For that purpose (listing available *properties*), I'd just go straight to the `style` object on an element: http://jsbin.com/itoyus/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/itoyus/1/edit)). In essence, `for (var name in document.createElement('div').style) { display(name); }` Works in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, probably others.

Comment: It was just an easy way to list styles and what they are set to -> http://jsfiddle.net/vXf9t/3/

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd need to refer to the different CSS specifications, for which browsers have varying levels of support: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work