# Is there any way to find the style related property values of an html element ? i wanted to load those values in my dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm getting style properties using this `CSSStyleDeclaration`. But my question is, when a user selects property in the property dropdown I wanted to give one more dropdown with predefined values of those property values..
how to do this?

For example: If I select table-layout as property, I want to give values dropdown with fixed, auto, etc. values...

```
var CSSStyleDeclaration = event.target.style;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are a million questions (and non-SO resources) about "how do I load dropdown B based on the choice in dropdown A". Search and try something, then if you get stuck, show us your code.

Comment: Please read this article to learn more about how to ask a good question so that we can better help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all available values of css property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771932/get-all-available-values-of-css-property)

Answer (score 0):

Make this dropdown button in your inner layout of table where you want to add more properties.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">properties</a>
    </div>
</div>
```