# Save all css properties of element using jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm basically trying to save all current css properties of an element in a local var/array.
I tried :

```
el.css();
```

and

```
el.css("*");
```

With no luck.

Is there any quick tip do to so ?

Comment: can you read my thoughts? i just wanted to ask this question because of my css hover problem! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/prevent-default-hover WOW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/save-all-css-properties-of-element-using-jquery

i have updated the answer to be more efficent also providing a working demo...

```
    $(function() {
        // element tag example p and element id
        function get_element_style(element, id){
            var css = {};
            $('<iframe id="get-style-'+id+'" style="display:none"/>').appendTo('body');
            $('#get-style-'+id).contents().find('body').append('</'+element+'>');
            $el = $('#get-style-'+id).contents().find('body').find(element);
            var defaults_css = $el.getStyles();
            $('#get-style-'+id).remove();
            var element_css = $('#'+id).getStyles();
            for (var i in element_css) {
                if (element_css[i] !== defaults_css[i]) {
                    css[i] = element_css[i];
                }
            } 
            return css;
        }

        var properties = get_element_style('p', 'test-p');

    });
```

the problem when getting the style of an element is that you don't get just setted value but also the default values. with this code i'm trying to get just the setted values of an element. this work both with `inline` style as well as with `<style>` and `<link>`

> - **NOTE:** this solution require the use of this plugin https://github.com/moagrius/copycss

Comment: This will only get CSS properties specified inline. Anything coming from an external CSS file or `<style>` tag won't show up.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
el.attr('style');
```

?

Also, this might interest you:

[How can I get list of all element css attributes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471118/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-element-css-attributes-with-jquery)

Comment: Doesn't your code assume all CSS styling is performed inline or through JS?