# How do I use addClass with a style based on selectors rather than a named class?

Tags: jquery, css

I have some css code that targets elements based on id name, etc. rather than being individually named:

```
.tzOptions li .subheader {
```

versus

```
.myClassName
```

How do I use jquery's addClass with the first version? I know with the named version, I can just do

```
$listItems.addClass('myClassName');
```

How do I handle the "hierarchical" version that contains not just a named class, but a named class that then contains a dom element that has another named class? I need to apply the styles that are applied to `.tzOptions li .subheader` to a different dom element, but don't want to have to duplicate the style code just so I can have a named class to apply.

**CLARIFICATION**

I really can't seem to explain this well. Here's what I have. I have a chunk of html:

```
<div id="options-reg-phone-type" class="tzOptions">
            <div class="scrollBlock">
                <ul id="dropdown-reg-phone-type">
                    <li>
                        <div class="header">Home</div>
                        <div class="subheader">info</div>
                        <div class="optkey">0</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="header">Work</div>
                        <div class="subheader">info</div>
                        <div class="optkey">1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="header">Cell</div>
                        <div class="subheader">info</div>
                        <div class="optkey">2</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a set of styles that are applied to the `div` elements with the `header` class:

```
.tzOptions li .header:hover { 
   color:#FFF; 
   font-size:14px; 
   font-weight:bold;
   line-height: 13px;
   padding-bottom:0;
}
```

What I want to do is, apply those same styles to the `div` elements with the `subheader` class. I don't want to have to duplicate my style code. The main issue is, I'm trying to duplicate mouseover code with keyboard input (i.e. use the arrow keys in a select). I know how to go about doing that; I just can't figure out how to apply the `:hover` styles from one element to another element (or how to use addClass with a pseudo selector like `:hover` at all.)

Comment: You would have to make the target element match the css selector by giving it a parent that has the `tzOptions` class, making it a child of an `li`, and then giving it the `subheader` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use addClass with a "dom" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130606/how-do-i-use-addclass-with-a-dom-element)

Comment: Make a new class. Your logic is backwards, adding js to dynamically define a class is going to create more overhead than duplicated classes. Just needing this also means you need to rethink your current styles since they're obviously not working right. The styles that need to be repeated often should be broken out so they can be applied on their own rather than encapsulating them in another class.

Comment: @RickCalder - I can't "rethink" my current styles; this is an enormous system that I'm only allowed access to a small part of. The styles are universal and I can't change or add anything to them.

Comment: >.< okay, fair enough. Carry on.

Comment: That's the whole reason I'm trying to get this crazy bit of script to work, rather than just creating a new class, which is the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to be able to add a class to elements that have the selector ".tzOptions li .subheader".

Why not use `$(".tzOptions li .subheader").addClass("myClassName");` ?

Comment: Nope, you don't understand the question. I have a style defined that does get applied to `.tzOptions li .subheader`. Now I want to apply those same styles to different elements, without having to define a named class that contains the same style code as what's defined for `.tzOptions li .subheader`.

Comment: Couldnt you just add another selector to the style block?

Comment: no, as I said in the comments to the OP, I cannot make any changes to the css.

Answer (score 0):

`addClass` is *not* for manipulating heirarchial declaration  ( although it can be)

It is for adding another `class` to the dom element. ( appending)

So it can have another /  more style behaviour

Jquery :

> It simply adds the class, appending it to any which may already be
>   assigned to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that. but you can make a function which will get all the css that is defined to a particular element (not a very good idea to fellow but you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471118/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-element-css-attributes-with-jquery)). and then apply that style to your element.

just give this a try

```
//Function to get all the css for a particular dom element

jQuery.fn.css2 = jQuery.fn.css;
jQuery.fn.css = function() {
    if (arguments.length) return jQuery.fn.css2.apply(this, arguments);
    var attr = ['font-family','font-size','font-weight','font-style','color',
        'text-transform','text-decoration','letter-spacing','word-spacing',
        'line-height','text-align','vertical-align','direction','background-color',
        'background-image','background-repeat','background-position',
        'background-attachment','opacity','width','height','top','right','bottom',
        'left','margin-top','margin-right','margin-bottom','margin-left',
        'padding-top','padding-right','padding-bottom','padding-left',
        'border-top-width','border-right-width','border-bottom-width',
        'border-left-width','border-top-color','border-right-color',
        'border-bottom-color','border-left-color','border-top-style',
        'border-right-style','border-bottom-style','border-left-style','position',
        'display','visibility','z-index','overflow-x','overflow-y','white-space',
        'clip','float','clear','cursor','list-style-image','list-style-position',
        'list-style-type','marker-offset'];
    var len = attr.length, obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        obj[attr[i]] = jQuery.fn.css2.call(this, attr[i]);
    return obj;
}
```