# Highlight all elements of a particular style (float) within a site

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, css-selectors

Does anybody know of a clever method or tool to either highlight, list or identify all elements within a webpage / site with a particular applied style?

Basically we have inherited a few sites to manage / eventually redesign - and the previous developers seem to have had some problems with clearing floats!  Think I've fixed the obvious issues - but as floats can be a strange beast and I'm paranoid (and also curious as to whether its possible) -  I wanted a way to highlight floated elements quickly so I can check their relative code.

Only method I thought of so far is reworking this javascript to run in the console [find all elements in a page with position "absolute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751317/find-all-elements-in-a-page-with-position-absolute) - but there must be an easier way!?

Comment: Does style (`float`) applied as inline or via class?

Comment: via a class - or variety of unfortunately (if that makes things more tricky!) . Was hoping there would be a chrome dev tool to handle it but nothing i can figure - thanks @Konrud

Comment: So as far as I understand you have several classes with the `float` set on them. So in that case the only way I can think of is using `querySelectorAll`. Example: 
`document.querySelectorAll(".f, .a").forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.classList.add("highlighted");
});`

Comment: great - thanks @konrud - so i could run this per page in the chrome console for example and add say a border and font color to highlight?

Comment: Exactly. Please try and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to search your css for `float: left|right` and add some nasty visible rule below. 
Also you can use `div[style*="float:left"]` selector to highlight inline styles.

Comment: cool - could this be automated to run in console as a script do you think?  This way it could be easily visible on the fly without iterating through many styles in teh style sheet

Comment: I don't think it's possible in browser console. But you can write script or just `ctrl+r` in IDE replacing `float: left;` with `float: left; background: chucknorris !important;` inside css files.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have several classes with the `float` set on them.
So, in that case the only way I can think of is using `querySelectorAll`.

Example:

For the class search (e.g. `<div class="f"></div>` or `<div class="a"></div>`)

```js
const elementsToHighlight = document.querySelectorAll(".f, .a");

elementsToHighlight.forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.classList.add("highlighted"); 
});
```

For inline style you can use the following code (we search for every HTML element that has its `float` property set via inline style) (e.g. `<div style="float: left;"></div>` or `<div style="float: right;"></div>`). Note that style attribute can have as many properties set as it desired that's why we use an asterisk to account for this case.

```js
const elementsToHighlight = document.querySelectorAll('[style*="float"]');

elementsToHighlight.forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.classList.add("highlighted"); 
});
```

Function that recursively traverses all HTMLElements in the DOM, checks their style and if HTMLElement has its `float` property set, adds `highlighted` class to this particular element.

**NOTE**: this code is **not efficient** it can be used for your purpose, though, If you want to run it in the console in order to find/debug all the elements that has a `float` set on them.

```js
// getting all the children of the `<body>` HTMLElement, but as `node.children` is `HTMLCollection` we need to convert it into an array.
const elems = Array.from(document.body.children);

function highlightElements (elems) {
    elems.forEach(function (elem) {
       if(elem.nodeType === 1) { // if it is HTML element
          if(elem.children.length > 0) highlightElement(Array.from(elem.children));
          if (window.getComputedStyle(elem).float !== "none") elem.classList.add("highlighted");
       }
    });
};
```

CSS

```css
.highlighted {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

In the example above we find all the elements that have particular class and then add them our own custom class that highlightes them. In our case is the `outline` property.

Comment: is there a way to manipulate this for style property - ie highlight classes that have a style property of float - or am i not understanding the code

Comment: searching through the style sheet there are 50 odd classes that have a float style in one site and 160 odd in another

Comment: @Dancer
"...is there a way to manipulate this for style property..." 
I'm not  quite sure what are you asking? Do you mean HTML element with an inline style set with `float` (e.g. `<div style"float: left;">`)?

Comment: hi @konrud - sorry - yes the style sheet has many iterations of the float style applied  in a multitude of classes - so i wondered whether we could iterate through the elements style properties - if they have a float style applied either by class or line - highlight as you have above?

Comment: @Dancer, I've updated the code, please see if it answer your question.

Comment: this looks great - thanks so much for your help @konrud - will try it now..

Comment: cheers @Konrud - in the example above I guess i'd need to know the specific class name that contains the float property and it wouldn't be possible to iterate through all elements and highlight an element if it contained the specific float:left style regardless fo its class name?  as the way the style shet is constructed there are 150 class names containing the float:left style

Comment: So if I understand you right, you don't want to know the specific class or if element has an inline style you just want to iterate over all elements in the DOM (page) and set `highlight` class if this particular element has `float` property set, am I right?

Comment: ideally - if this is possible - that would be perfect - i could then take a quick look page to page.

Comment: @Dancer, I've update the code and added the function which is traverses (recursively) all HTMLElements in the DOM and adds `highlighted` class if HTMLElement has the `float` property set.

Comment: nice one - almost perfect!  just get this error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'elems' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: you deserve a beer for this to be fair!

Comment: Try to refresh the site and change `const elems  = Array.from(document.body.children);
` into `var elems  = Array.from(document.body.children);`

Comment: @Dancer, if my answer helped you please mark it as resolved.

Comment: still same error i'm afraid - does it work in your console?

Comment: @Dancer, yes it does.