# How to convert a HTMLElement to a string putting all css in style tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to convert a HTMLElement to a string putting all css styles (including the ones created dynamically with javascript) in style tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by accessing the outerHTML property

```
$("your element selector").prop("outerHTML");
```

This will return a string value of the object with any inline styling included.

This won't include styling included in separate css files.  If this is something you do need then I would recommend looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-ele) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965310/get-all-css-attributes-with-jquery) previous question.

Comment: but I need to get all styles that browser use to render element

Comment: Edited my answer to include a previous question that answer how to get ALL css properties. Just out of curiosity what are you trying to achieve, would something like .clone() not be sufficient?

Comment: I will save it as an image using rasterizeHTML.js and I need element looks exactly as in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the styles is not really an options there are css rules, inline styles and user agent styles that affects the actual look too.

You can always use jQuery `css()` method to get the calculated values of an element: [ref css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$(ele).css('height'); //Most of common properties are supported
```

But that will not do the work you are after.

> I will save it as an image using rasterizeHTML.js and I need element looks exactly as in browser.

If that is your goal I can suggest you use other methods and libraries that already does a good job: [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html)

in html2canvas the results are pretty accurate and the major limit is with images - but there are several methods to overcome that such as using the images as backgrounds.

Hope I helped.