# How do I get a computed style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-domain, computed-style

Can anybody please help me with a script.. or a way to get the value of

```
height : 1196px;
width: 284px;
```

from the computed style sheet (webkit).  I know IE is different- as usual.  I cannot access the iframe (cross domain)—I just need the height/width.

Screenshot of what I need (circled in red).  How do I access those properties?

[image]

Source

```
<iframe id="frameId" src="anotherdomain\brsstart.htm">
 <html id="brshtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
    \--I WANT THIS ELEMENTS COMPUTED BROWSER CSS HEIGHT/WIDTH

<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

<body>
 BLA BLA BLA STUFF

</body>

</html>
   \--- $('#frameId').context.lastChild.currentStyle 
        *This gets the actual original style set on the other domain which is "auto"
        *Now how to getComputed Style?


</iframe>
```

The closest I got is this

```
$('#frameId').context.lastChild.currentStyle
```

That gives me the actual style on the HTML element which is "auto" and that is true as thats what's its set on the iframed document.

How do I get the computed style that all the browsers use to calculate the scroll bars, and inspect elements values?

Using Tomalaks answer I conjured up this lovely piece of script for webkit

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("frameId"), null).getPropertyValue("height")
```

or

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("frameId"), null).getPropertyCSSValue("height").cssText
```

Result      150px

Identical to

```
$('#frameId').height();
```

So I got them to add a id of 'brshtml' to the head- maybe it will help me select the element easier. Webkit inspection shows me now html#brshtml but I cant select it using `getelementbyid`

Comment: Look in the "related" section of this page...

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use element.offsetWidth and element.offsetHeight properties but it actually is hard to tell what you really want from your post.

Comment: yes- i can use any scripting i want. For life i cacnnot get to those values.. i want to set the iframe height based on the computed style.. if i use jquery to get the iframes.docuemnt.height -- Bleee- access denied- for gods sake- so how does the browsers knwo its 1196px??! and its there! so how do i get it :D pretty please

Comment: i have read (several * several) articles from SO -- i cannot get a working answer

Comment: Which height and width do you actually need? The size of the iframe window of the size of the iframe contents? Please clarify.

Comment: i need the size of the HTML - the very first element in the iframe. Which is 1196x284. But cross domain policy forbids me to query that

Comment: Can you manipulate the contents of both frames? In other words can you put a little script in the iframe and another one  and in the outer document?

Comment: I can- but that is an absolute last resort because it can cause long term problems with management form their side.. i really need the answer to this question.. it must be possible

Comment: @ppumkin: If you have already tried several of the _many_ solutions available on Stack Overflow, why don't you show us what you tried and _specifically_ what is not working with them?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-ele/1020560#1020560).

> It's not jQuery but, in Firefox, Opera
>   and Safari you can use
>   `window.getComputedStyle(element)` to
>   get the computed styles for an element
>   and in IE you can use
>   `element.currentStyle`. The returned
>   objects are different in each case,
>   and I'm not sure how well either work
>   with elements and styles created using
>   Javascript, but perhaps they'll be
>   useful.

The `iframe` looks about 150px high to me. If its *contents* are 1196px high (and indeed, you appear to be exploring the `html` node, according to the screenshot) and that's what you want to get, then you should [navigate into the DOM of the iframe's document](http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/) and apply the above technique to that.

Comment: Thank you! I tested it chrome debug  like this and this is the relult   window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("frameId"), null).getPropertyValue("height"): 150px    It should be 1196px  Its driving me mental

Comment: In your screenshot, the `iframe` _does_ look to be about 150px high. The red circled bit is indicating that your `html` element is 1196px. Did you mean to venture into the `iframe`'s DOM?

Comment: In IE you can use the `element.currentStyle` property.

Comment: @geekchic: Yes, that's what my answer says.

Comment: Yes the iframe is exactly 150px but i am looking for the highlighted Iframes DOM HTML element which is 1196x284 - that is what I have been trying to get

Comment: how would i traverse to the iframes HTML element. in jquery i would use $('#frameId html')  but using the javascript window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("frameId html"), null)  is obvoisly incorrect

Comment: @Tomalak Ha, so it does. Skimming fail.

Comment: also i got them to add an ID to the html tag so it read <html id="brshtml" ...    and i try to select that- = null

Comment: @ppumkin: Oh you did say "I cannot access the iframe (cross domain)". If that's true, then you're SOL.

Comment: yea- but surely there must be a way to get the computed sytle in our domain(browser)?? because my screen shot shows that the values are there. How does chrome get those values for eg?

Comment: or i read somewhere a few times, when i did not need it that the outside domain can add my domain in to somewhere to loosen this restriction? But I cannot for life find it now-- if thats the case do you know about this? Or maybe joining our domains somehow for a more permanently solution on our servers?

Comment: @ppumkin: By traversing the DOM.

Comment: with jquery i managed to get the original values of the HTML height css which is "auto" and other styles which match up..... surely there must be a method to get the calculated style.. so annoying

Comment: @ppumkin: All the available techniques are described in detail above. Combine them for great success.

Comment: Thanks for your time! this is my 2nd day of combining them :D If i am not successful in 3 hours then .. have no idea..

Comment: @Kerin: Yea yea yea :) i thought i was on to something..which kinda i was but not all the way. @Tomalak - I cannot even access scrollTop() of the iframe to determine to enlarge or decrease the size of the iframe(this works on document.body) Complete and epic fail question :( Going to use easyxdm for now.. PS Thanks Again!

Comment: [getComputedStyle](https://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle) is available in all browsers now, inc. ie11

Answer (score 12):

looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Use **.clientWidth** to get an integer width in px.

```
<div id="mydiv" style="border:1px solid red;">This is DIV contents.</div>
<button onclick="alert(
document.getElementById('mydiv').clientWidth);">
   Click me to see DIV width in px
</button>
```

Comment: That returns the sizes of the frame not the internal page. Why? Because of Cross Site Rules deniying acces to the "client" page so it falls back to the iFrame- The debugger re-renders the HTML and does not use any API to get the actrual client width. So Your answer is wrong in many ways. I just do not want to down vote a newbie

Comment: @ppumkin This does exactly the same thing as Width when it comes to div. Dunno about [i]frames. Got a link to some docs or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery solution:**

```
$(".element").outerWidth( true ); 
//A Boolean indicating whether to include the element's 
//margin in the calculation.
```

**Description**: Get the ***current computed width*** for the first element in the set of matched elements, ***including padding and border***. Returns an integer (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

You can read more about [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) / [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) at api.jquery.com

***Note:** the selected element must not be "display:none" (in this case you will get only the paddings as total width without the inner width )*

Answer (score 0):

*If* you're already using jQuery, you can use [`CSS`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to get the computed /current for any style property in any browser.

```js
$("#el").css("display")
```

```js
var $el = $("#el");

console.log(".css('display'): " + $el.css("display"))

var el = document.getElementById("el");
el.currentStyle = el.currentStyle || el.style

console.log("style.display: " + el.style.display)
console.log("currentStyle.display: " + el.currentStyle.display)
console.log("window.getComputedStyle: " + window.getComputedStyle(el).display)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="el">element</div>
```