# JavaScript: convert ex to px

Tags: javascript

So I'm reading elem.style.width, and getting something like "3.1415926ex".

I would like to convert this to "px."

Does JavaScript have built in functions to do this? I'd prefer that chopping off last 2 letters of string, reading it as a number, and multiplying it by a magic constant.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, no built-in conversion function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "magic constant" because there is no straight-forward conversion from `ex` to `px` (unlike, say, converting inches to centimetres).

An `ex` unit is the height of the lowercase 'x' character in the current font (where a "font" is a combination of typeface family (e.g. Times New Roman), size (say, 14px or 72pt), and style (regular, bold, italic)).

...so "1ex" in 72pt Impact Bold is larger than "1ex" in 8pt Helvetica Regular.

Converting from `ex` to `px` can be done if you know these details. Of course, it sounds like you really just want the "computed style", which is always in pixels. Read this: [How do I get a computed style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style)

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in function for the purpose. Given an element that is accessible in JavaScript using the variable `elem`, you can get its width in pixels, rounded to an integer, using the expression [`elem.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth). To get it as unrounded, with precision varying by browser, you can in principle use `elem.getBoundingClientRect().width` instead, though it will in practice yield a rounded result or an inaccurate result in many browsers. – This applies if the horizontal padding of the element is zero.

If you set, say, the width of an element to `1ex` and then apply the above to it, you will get an integer or a real number that tells you the value of `ex` in pixels. But it’s not a magic constant: it depends on the font family and on the font size.

Note: Some old browsers, such as IE 7, incorrectly implement the `ex` unit just as half of the `em` unit, instead of properly using the x-height of the font.