# Measure ex in px in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

### What I want to do

I would like to *measure* the 1ex in px.

### What I have learned

- 1ex is a **relative** unit -- equal to the height of lower case "x" of the font in use:

An instructive image describing the situation:

[image]

link to CSS spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths

- `window.getComputedStyle('foo',null).height` or `jQuery('#foo').height()` does not help -- because they return the height of its *bounding box*.  e.g.

  ```
  <div id="upper"> X </div>
  <div id="lower"> x </div>
  <script>
     var upper = $('#upper').height();
     var lower = $('#lower').height();
     console.log(upper === lower);
  </script>
  ```

  The last line gives `true`.
- Related pages, but not fully informative to me:

  - [jQuery/JavaScript: convert pixels to em in a easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305993/jquery-javascript-convert-pixels-to-em-in-a-easy-way)
  - [How do I get a computed style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style?lq=1)
  - [JavaScript: convert ex to px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470954/javascript-convert-ex-to-px)

Any information is appreciated!

EDIT:

Some people suggests that this is a dupe of

[JavaScript: convert ex to px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470954/javascript-convert-ex-to-px)

but there are **NO ACTUAL answers**:  The first answer explains only *relativity* of `1ex` and the second one is even **wrong** -- `document.getElementById('upper').style.height` returns `"" // empty char`.

Comment: 1 ex equals 6 pixels in both windows and linux, and in most browsers as default. so shouldn't be to hard to figure out, even if it is the most useless unit of all time.

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Em_units_versus_ex_units

Comment: I mistook the id as an indication of a css property for font size. Large is referring to a capital X, while small refers to lowercase. I didn't catch that.

Comment: thanks anyway!  I renamed those ids to avoid confusion.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392868/javascript-find-divs-line-height-not-css-property-but-actual-line-height

Comment: The questions are similar but there wasn't enough answer there as I wrote above!

Comment: It’s clearly a duplicate. If the answers to the old question are not adequate, we should try and improve them, instead of spawning new copies of a question, resulting in the same question asked multiple times with different sets of answers.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, I think I get your point.  In your definition, this may be called a "duplicate".  Yes, the same question has already been raised, and the answers are already "accepted".  I agree, it is the questioner who determines whether he/she had an answer.  But that answer, in this case, is not enough TO ME (actually I guess that was not enough for everyone).  That's why, I think, it is worth raising this question again.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I can think of:

- Fill a canvas with white
- Draw the letter on the canvas in black
- Measure the vertical distance between the first non-white pixel to the last non-white pixel

You should be able to achieve this using `getImageData`.

Alternatively you could also try using the canvas method `measureText` which should return the width of the text string passed in. Considering `x` is often quite symmetrical, you could get reasonably accurate results with just that.

Comment: This does not work with fonts that do no have the letter "x". The unit ex has nothing to do with the actual "x" as Illya mentions below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the current CSS spec says about `ex` unit:

> Equal to the used x-height of the ... font. The x-height is so called because it is *often* equal to the height of the lowercase "x".
>   However, an ‘ex’ is defined even for fonts that do not contain an "x".
>
> The x-height of a font can be found in different ways. Some fonts contain reliable metrics for the x-height. If reliable font metrics
>   are not available, UAs may determine the x-height from the height of a
>   lowercase glyph. One possible heuristic is to look at how far the
>   glyph for the lowercase "o" extends below the baseline, and subtract
>   that value from the top of its bounding box. In the cases where it is
>   impossible or impractical to determine the x-height, a value of 0.5em
>   must be assumed.

So 'x-height' doesn't have to do anything with the actual character "x", it's just a font metric, either stored in the font file or calculated by the browser. And the best way to measure it, IMO, is to create a test block with the same font properties, set to it, e.g., `width: 10ex` and then measure its `clientWidth` (or jQuery's `width()`).

Comment: As I pasted a link above, I know the spec of 'ex'.. but thanks, your solution actually works. (Though I was not talking about 'width' but 'height'.)

Comment: Just a note to future visitors that `clientWidth` and jQuery's `.width()` rounds down the value. If you need accurate measurement, use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) instead.

Comment: Also be aware that the ratio of ex to px may differ between height and width...

Comment: Jthrope, isn't this because of the rounding mentioned above, so slightly different ratio for different values, not different directions?