# Why won't javascript return the style properties?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Return Width</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #foo { background: green; width: 80px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getWidth() {
            alert(document.getElementById("foo").style.width);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="foo" onClick="getWidth()">
    Hello World
</div>
```

I have been trying to return several properties including `width` and `backgroundColor` and what I'm finding is that I can set the properties but I can't return them. Why?

Comment: You *can*  access the properties that way, but `#foo` *has no* `style` attribute?

Comment: Is there a way I can reference the styles applied through the cascade?

Comment: Then see [How do i get a computed style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style)

Comment: @Bergi Is there a way I can reference the width in the css file? Or should I just set the width attribute in the html tag?

Comment: Setting the `style` attribute (via `el.style.width = …;`) is the simplest and best for single elements. However, it is [possible](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript) to reference and change the applied stylesheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` property references the styles applied directly to the element (via the `style` property or the `style` attribute). It doesn't reference styles applied through the cascade.

For that, you want [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: Is there a way I can reference the width in the css?

Answer (score 3):

That only works for inline styles. USe [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) for CSS set via non-inline styles.

```
function getWidth() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("foo");
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("width");
    alert(theCSSprop);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rTaD5/)**

Answer (score 1):

depending on the property you need to access, you have other methods, like `offsetwidth` and `offsetheight.` getComputedStyles doesn`t work on ie7 and ie8, though you could try this, is cross browser

```
function getStyle(el, cssprop){
 if (el.currentStyle) //IE
  return el.currentStyle[cssprop]
 else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) //Firefox
  return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop]
 else //try and get inline style
  return el.style[cssprop]
}
```

Comment: Ok. How can I get the `cssprop`so I can pass it to function getStyle()?

Comment: cssprop is the parameter, you can put the style property you like, width, height, color, etc... you can call it like getStyle(element, 'height'); for example