# keep sticky div with same width when you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want sticky div to be of same width when its get sticky.
right now it contains 100% width and take full area at top.
My requirement is to keep it within outer div.

Fiddle example is:

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sharan_thethy/e8xwp/)

code:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="main-cont">
<div id="unstickyheader">
    <p>This is some text that comes before our <strong>Sticky
    Header</strong></p>

    <p>This is some text that comes before our <strong>Sticky
    Header</strong></p>

    <p>This is some text that comes before our <strong>Sticky
    Header</strong></p>
  </div>

  <div id="stickyheader">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>Sticky Text 1</td>

        <td>Sticky Text 2</td>

        <td>Sticky Text 3</td>

        <td>Sticky Text 4</td>

        <td>Sticky Text 5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="stickyalias"></div>

  <div id="othercontent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    </p>       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    ulpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    table { background: black; color: white;}
            body, td {
                    font: 13px sans-serif;
            }
      .main-cont{
          width:500px;
border:2px solid red;
      }
            #stickyheader {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 10px;
            }
            #stickyalias {
              display: none;
              height: 10px;
            }
            #unstickyheader {
              margin-bottom: 15px;
background:yellow;
width:100%;
            }
            #othercontent {
              margin-top: 20px;
            }
```

**Script: onload**

```
$(function(){
        // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                        $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                        $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                        $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
                }
        });
  });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

**Please note i have used bootstrap 3 classes.
500px is static use col-md-7 class for this.
I need it responsive i cant make it fix.
Sorry for fiddle example that is of fix width.**

Comment: How'd like to experiment with [position sticky](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)?

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS for strikyheader and try [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/e8xwp/3/)

```
#stickyheader {
                 width: inherit;//use !important and try
                 height: 10px;//use !important and try
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion (width:inherit) its working on example but not working on actual project's code.

Comment: Make sure any of your project CSS value is overriding .. check it using Inspect element in you browser ...

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS property `position` is `static` or `relative` the width is automatically that one of the parent. To set it to `100%` is not neccessary.

But if you set `position` to absolute the width is that one of the next parent which `position` is `relative`. If there is no parent like that it gets the width of window.

Calculate the width before and set it to the element.
[How do I get a computed style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style) or set it to `inherit` like @kamesh said. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sharan_thethy/e8xwp/)...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a `width:'500px` to the `stickyheader` like this

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
     if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
          $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px',width:'500px'});
          $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
                $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
         }
  });
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e8xwp/6/)

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8xwp/9/) also  . Interactive based on the width of `main-cont div`.

Comment: I need to keep it responsive so i Cant give it fix width.
You may set it to 500px to 50%.

Comment: ya. you can use that inner div width. i just used `500` since u have given that 500 as width of inner one. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e8xwp/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try

Note both properties and values of `.css()` quoted

```
if ( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
   $('#stickyheader')
   .css({"position": 'fixed', "top": '0px', "max-width":"500px"});
   $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/Q7bSp/

Comment: No, that's not the problem. jQuery knows both terminologies and can combine them.