# id.styles is showing nothing

Tags: javascript, console

I'm not sure if I'm going to completely crazy or if there's something wrong with my computer.

I have a simple piece of JavaScript below but when I console log the style object it is completely empty. This is despite the fact the the element in question clearly has styles attached to it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

    #para{  
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid red;      
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="para" class="paraDiv">This is the div</div>

<script>
        window.onload = function(){
            var d = document.getElementById('para');    
            console.dir(d);
            console.log(d.style.top);
        }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get a computed style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `style` property only gets information about styles applied inline via an element's `style` attribute. It doesn't contain any information about styles inherited from other elements or declared in style sheets.

Instead, you want [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle), which will give you the information you're looking for.

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(para).top);
```

Comment: Well I'm dumb struck. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful. When the five minute timer runs out I will definitely accept the answer. Thanks for the quick help.