# How can we get height and width of an element calculated by chrome using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

When we inspect element on chrome browser its shows height and width of that element. So my question is that can we get that calculated height and width using any scripting language like javascript or any external api?

[image]

Comment: [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), [How do i get a computed style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style)

Comment: If you have jQuery available, try one of methods width(), outerWidth(), innerWidth(), height(), innerHeight(), outerHeight(). See https://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/

Comment: yes i have tried them all. But the result is not satisfactory

Comment: I have tried .width(), .offsetwidth, .clientWidth, but it none of them is able to give the exact value like chrome.

Comment: tried $(element).offset().top  and $(element).offset().left from jquery??

Comment: yes i have tried $(element).offset().top and $(element).offset().left  but i want height and width of that element.

Comment: And where is the code you've been trying? Post a demo in a fiddle to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var height = document.getElementById(<id of the element>).offsetHeight;
var width = document.getElementById(<id of the element>).offsetWidth;
```

in a JavaScript file, embedded on that page if that is what you are searching for.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page0002.css" /></head>
<body style="margin:0;background-color:#808080;width:100%;height:100%;">
<div id="Page" class="PageContainer" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:1064px;height:1362px;">
<div id="TextContainer2">

<div id="jpedal" style="position:relative;">
<div id="t1_2" class="t s1_2">Problem Solving</div>
<div id="t2_2" class="t s2_2">Problem Solving</div>
<div id="t3_2" class="t s3_2">Name</div>
<div id="t4_2" class="t s4_2">© Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company</div>

Comment: This is a sensible answer that is not right in all cases. things like flex screw this up.

Answer (score 0):

Ondra is right,

you need to include jQuery and the following code will get you started (based on the element you've highlighted (The first function() line is to make sure your document is ready:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  width = $('div#t8_2').width();
  height = $('div#t8_2').height();
});
</script>
```

Edit: Seems to me like you're trying to calculate Text width and not an element's width.

I'm taking the answer from this question from philfreo:

[Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery)

Here's his jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/MqM76/

That should work.

Comment: Chrome shows 408px width but .width() shows 1470px.

Comment: Can I see part of your html code with div#t8_2 and whatever elements are inside?

And what if you try google's full css path as follow:

    width = $('div#t8_2.t.s7_2').width();