# Reset css style for a div content

Tags: html, css

There is a html page customized with css styles(I cannot change this css). One  tag of this page designed as a container for dynamic html data. How can I "reset" css settings for this div(css styles defined in the page have no influence on the content of this div)?

**I have access only to dynamic html and I can add more css styles to a page.**

Comment: Post the parent CSS you need to modify.

Comment: are the css styles defined before or after the dynamic css styles? Have you tried to make the styles more specific for the div?

Comment: Css styles of the main page can be different each time

Comment: Have you tried using !important?

Comment: If you REALLY need to reset the style, which I wouldn't recommend performance-wise, you can modify the plugin getting the computed style to reset everything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the problem you have having is that the CSS for the main page is affecting the CSS for your "dynamic" div. For the most part there is nothing you can do about that, other than specifying higher-priority styles to the dynamic content you are loading.

You can do this by doing in-line css, or by doing other more specific CSS declarations in a file or  tags.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not to "reset" the styles, but rather to SET the styles you want on the div, to override whatever the page styles throw at you.  In your situation you'll need to either edit the style attribute, or modify the javascript style properties.