# Find CSS rules of an individual class

Tags: jquery, css

If I have an element -

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

myDiv has some rules applied to it -

```css
.myDiv {
    background:red;
}
```

I then apply another class to myDiv -

```
$('.myDiv').addClass('newClass');
```

There's a definition in my css like this -

```
.myDiv.newClass{
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
```

How can I find out what rules apply specifically to $('.myDiv.newClass')? I would like a function that returns an object with the css rules in.

The result would be something like this -

```
{
    "position":"relative",
    "left":"20px"
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want return any rules that apply only to .myDiv

In which case you should remove this class from your element and change your CSS structure:

```
$('.myDiv').addClass('newClass');    
$('.myDiv').removeClass('myDiv');
```

Then change:

```
.myDiv.newClass {}
```

to:

```
.newClass {}
```

If you need to see what styles are now being applied to that div, you can "[Inspect Element](https://superuser.com/questions/4640/what-is-the-inspect-element-feature-in-google-chrome)" using [Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/4640/what-is-the-inspect-element-feature-in-google-chrome) or [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Does `$('.myDiv').addClass('newClass');` really works ? You don't have `myDiv` class anymore at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was unclear in my question. I've edited to show what I'd like returned.

Answer (score 0):

`window.getComputedStyle()` maybe what you are looking for - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

a very nice article about fetching the styles - browser compatible

[**Quirks**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

The above given like is a generalised solution to your problem.