# get CSS from external class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**edit**
added a test with regexpr to solve the problem techfoobar pointed out

**edit 2**
corrected code for others hf :)

I'm looking for a way to get all static styles from a specified class. I don't want to append a new div and extract all possible values from it because values are often just computed...

Here are some related posts:

[jQuery CSS plugin that returns computed style of element to pseudo clone that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el)

[Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html

This is what i came up so far:

```
function getExternalCSS(className) {
    var cssText = false;
    $.each(document.styleSheets, function(key, value) {
        $.each(value.cssRules, function(k, v) {
            if(new RegExp(className, "i").test(v.selectorText)) {
                cssText = v.cssText;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(cssText !== false) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return cssText;
}
```

css to browse:

```
.someClass {
    style1...
}
.someOtherClass {
    style2...
}
.myClassToFind {
    style3...
}
```

usage:

```
    getExternalCSS(".myClassToFind");  //note the . for class
```

The selectorText is returned correctly, but the `if` is never triggered. I already tried to parse to string etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XaB3T/1/

There were a couple of problems:

a) You need to `return false` from a `$.each` to stop the looping, its like `break`. This was not being done.
b) You were checking `v.selectorText.toLowerCase()` with `'.myClass'` which surely cannot match since `'.myClass'` is not all small case

---

**Explanation** for `For counting in only those styles that will be applied at the end, you might need to do a lot more!`

For CSS specificity rules, please refer to:

- http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity
- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

---

The `if` never returns true because:

a) The selector text need not be exactly `.yourClass`. It can be `.a .yourClass`, `div.yourClass` or even `.anotherClass, .yourClass` etc.. all pointing to your element

b) The check needs to be something like:

```
for each selectorText {
   strip off any { character
   split the selector text by ',' into an array called parts
   for each part {
      check if it ends with '.yourClass' // if it does, this class is match
   }
}
```

Another problem is CSS specificity. For counting in only those styles that will be applied at the end, you might need to do a lot more!

Comment: i know that this is just a small version and it will need more improvments to cover all classes. but in my testcase the selector was just .myClassToFind so it should match...

Comment: cant you explain or give a link what you mean by this plz:For counting in only those styles that will be applied at the end, you might need to do a lot more!

Comment: Pls check my update above. I believe this is what you were looking for.