# I am writing a jQuery plugin that will add a parent div to each image on a page.. what CSS issues should I consider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm writing my first jQuery plugin and part of the functionality involves dynamically generating a "frame div" around each image on a page.  The frame has to fit "snug" around the image, as it serves as the relative parent of an absolutely positioned overlay image that is dynamically added.

I want this to be unobtrusive obviously.  What can I do to minimize the side effects it will have on a user's own CSS?  I guess there are certain problem situations that will be unavoidable, right?  I'm thinking for ex. if the user CSS has targeted images with..

```
div.gallery > img
```

..child selectors to give them border/margin/etc, as one example.

Is it impossible to dynamically generate a parent div of an element in a way that is "safe" on unknown pages? Will there always be a risk of breaking the user CSS?

I suppose I can always just give a warning in the documentation, but I would love to make it idiot-proof if possible.

It just occurred to me that I could use JQ to read any CSS on the contained IMG .. and then transfer any properties "up" to the new parent div.  Is this crazy?

Comment: You could give your modified elements a class and let the user fix it.

Comment: Thats how Im heading so far .. the user adds a class of "foo" to the images they want affected, and then I generate a "fooFrame".  But it just occurred to me that I hadn't thought out all the CSS ramifications of that.  So I was wondering if there were any secret recipies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could copy all styles. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416477/825789) even shows a plugin to get all computed styles cross-browser. But that would be an overkill, wouldn't it? If you really want to have that, add it as an option (that defaults to `false`, preferably). Then let the users fix it by styling the class you provide, as Blender suggested in the comments.

Comment: I'll mark this as the solution.  It seems that any other strategy is far more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the selector .css, or .height or .width to get any dimension properties of the image, and then generate the div based on that. 
For example,

```
thisWidth = $('theImage').width();
thisHeight = $('theImage').height();

$('yourFrame').css({'height':thisHeight,'width':thisWidth});
```

Hope this is of some help...

Comment: Doing that for *all possible styles* would be a little boring.

Comment: well its a starting point. If you use a for each loop for each image then its pretty convenient. but perhaps I'm missing the crux of your question..

Comment: I see what you are suggesting and it is a way to try to get the frame "snug" but it wouldn't help if the user had margin-left:30px on his image for ex.   So I think I'm just going to put in the docs that there will be an extra div generated and let the user deal with it.