# jQuery get other tag's css and add it to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, greasemonkey

I'm trying to search the net, but no result...
Simple; how can I get other tag's css and add it to other on click?
For example:

I have `b` tag with css. I need to copy it's css to `a` tag on click.

```
var css = $('b').css();

$('.switch > a').click(function() {
    $(this).css(css);
});
```

Is it something like this?

Comment: yes, but it didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery CSS plugin that returns computed style of element to pseudo clone that element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el)

Answer (score 0):

use cssText to get and set all the current styles

```
var css = $('b').css('cssText');

$('.switch > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('cssText', css);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/chFtj/)

Comment: Well, code creates style tag but it won't put anything in it. Could it be because of my old jquery version, 1.5.2?

Comment: @aksu - Yes, this trick requires jQuery 1.8 or above, as those versions will "polyfill" cssText with the currentStyles etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which class is on your id, just do something like that

```
$('#YourId').attr('class', 'yourCssClass');
```

If you don't know it's class:

```
var classA = $('#YourId').attr('class');
$('#YourIdB').attr('class', classA);
```

Comment: The `b` tag doesn't have any classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newclass= $('b').attr('class');

$('.switch > a').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('class','newclass');
});
```

Comment: The `b` tag doesn't have any classes.