# How to get the computed style of the current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, google-chrome-extension

I want to get the computed style of the current element using JS,
I am able to fetch the other attributes but am stuck at when it come to css.

here is my code , please help

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var dom_id = e.target.id.toString();

 var dom_class = e.target.className.toString();
 var dom_el = e.target.toString();
 var dom_html = e.target.innerHTML;


  document.getElementById('ospy_id').value = dom_id;
  document.getElementById('ospy_class').value = dom_class;
  document.getElementById('ospy_el').value = dom_el;
           }, 
    false);
```

Comment: Have you checked here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle

Comment: @elclanrs I am developing a chrome plugin , which gives the attributes of the current element .

Comment: @CleanX: Then your question is incorrect. You've specifically asked for the *computed* style, but accepted an answer that gives you only the styles assigned on the element, not from stylesheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following statement to get css of any element

```
document.getElementById(elementid).style.property

example:
document.getElementById("ospy_class").style.color
```

Comment: It won't give you **computed** styles, if element has `margin: var(--margin-s)`, then `Element.style.margin` will be "var(--margin-s)" (not e.g. "8px")

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery (based on tags you're) you can do something along the lines of:

```
  $("#elementID").css("color");
```

etc...... [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: I am getting the attributes of the target element. So i will not have the class ID as such

Comment: Which element are you trying to get the css of ? dom_id ? If so it would be `$("#" + dom_id).css("color");` and so on for other elements

Answer (score 0):

It's not jQuery but, in Firefox, Opera and Safari you can use **window.getComputedStyle(element)** to get the computed styles for an element and in IE you can use **element.currentStyle**. The returned objects are different in each case, and I'm not sure how well either work with elements and styles created using Javascript, but perhaps they'll be useful.

please refer below url...

[jQuery CSS plugin that returns computed style of element to pseudo clone that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el/1020560#1020560)

Comment: you can use getComputedStyle in IE.