# copy CSS styles that apply to an element

Tags: javascript, css

I want to be able to get as output to the console (or something like this) all the style *rules* that apply to an element. Such that for example `$(_element_).css_styles();` generates output like:

- *element* { *style* }
- *.class* { *style* }
- *super* > *element* { *style* }
- *neighbor* + *element* { *style* }

How can I get this?

edit: I built a [jfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ds2F/1/) that looks good.

Comment: Why aren't Firebug or Chrome/Firefox debugger tools enough ?

Comment: @Demurgos because they inject non-CSS text.. and they also do no not lend themselves to recursively scanning a tree of elements and compiling all the CSS.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6416477/2081384) for a crossbrowser solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Chrome, you can use `getMatchedCSSRules(element)`.  If you're on FireFox (or another Gecko browser), a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/ydaniv/3033012) is available.