# Can you Make CSS Styles Stay When Copied/pasted?

Tags: css, copy-paste

Is it possible to make it so that when a user copies/pastes something onto their clipboard, it's CSS styles remain?

Comment: Copy and paste what? Text? Graphics? Something else?

Comment: i dont think you can control the endusers clipboard. only the text gets copied onto the clipboard when a user selects a certain section of the page

Comment: No that is impossible.

Comment: @Josiah I mean `text-shadow`, `font-weight`, `color`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about HTML objects, then you can use this script mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-ele).

This script copies all the styles of a HTML Tag and stores them so that you can use them later on.

So in your case, when you somehow detect the `copy event`, you can store the style properties of the original object, and when the user pastes, you can apply the stored styles.

The original usege of the script :

```
var style = $("#original").getStyleObject(); // copy all computed CSS properties
$("#original").clone() // clone the object
    .parent() // select it's parent
    .appendTo() // append the cloned object to the parent, after the original
                // (though this could really be anywhere and ought to be somewhere
                // else to show that the styles aren't just inherited again
    .css(style); // apply cloned styles
```

---

But maybe the easier way would be to add a class like `.copied-tag` when the user copies an object, then when the user pastes, you can find the `.copied-tag` class and apply any of the styles you want to copy.

An example:

When user copies:

```
$("#copied-object").addClass("copied-tag");
```

And when the user pastes:

```
originalObject = $(".copied-tag").removeClass("copied-tag"); 
newObject      = $(originalObject)
                     .clone()
                     .css("text-shadow", $(originalObject).css("text-shadow"))
                     .css("color",       $(originalObject).css("color"));

$("#container").append(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if the styles are inline like this:

```
<p style="color:red">some text</p>
```

and they copy paste it into something that reads html.