# all DOM element style properties returns empty string

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Please check out code below. This is simple div element with black background. So I'm trying to get background value via JavaScript. But get empty string.

HTML:

```
<div id="box1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    #box1 {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #000;
    }
```

JS:

```
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');

    console.log('backgroundColor: ' + box1.style.backgroundColor);
    console.log('background: ' + box1.style.background);
    console.log('width: ' + box1.style.width);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('backgroundColor: ' + box1.style.backgroundColor);
        console.log('background: ' + box1.style.background);
        console.log('width: ' + box1.style.width);
    }, 1000);
```

I'm shocked, but result is empty string:

Screenshots:

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSx9I.png)

[Mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAbbP.png)

jsfiddle.net/kcg96gdc/

Comment: You need to get the computed style. I think there is a duplicate of this question somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: `element.style` only gets inline styles

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1020560/3011082